# Xtify SDK not working for x86_64 (arm64 architecture)

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, xtify

We are trying to integrate Xtify SDK in our iPhone and iPad apps for receiving PUSH notifications and when we use tried, we are getting linker errors. I believe the Xtify SDK is not compiled with the arm64 architecture and that is the reason we are getting this error. Can anyone confirm this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Later iOS Xtify library versions are compiled with the standard architectures (armv7 and arm64 - but not armv7s, which is no longer standard as of Xcode 6 - see [Xcode 6 Standard architectures exclude armv7s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040497/xcode-6-standard-architectures-exclude-armv7s)). You will need to use version 2.74 or higher to compile on Xcode 6.x.