# Error ITMS-9000 Invalid Architectures x86_64, i386

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload a build to Itunes Connect but I have several errors raised during "Verifying assets with Itunes Connect" step.
All of these errors are here because of a**n Unsupported architecture x86_64 i386** contained into a third party frameworks (SKMaps.framework from Scout SDK).

Thanks to a Build Phases script found here : http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/
I managed to delete the x86_64, i386 as shown with a lipo -info command :

> MacBook:~ Karl$ lipo -info /Users/Karl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/SKMaps.framework/SKMaps
>   Architectures in the fat file are: **armv7 arm64**

However I still have the issue when uploading. It seems that I only delete the architecture in the Debug version of SKMaps.framework, and not the Release version ....

Would you have any suggestion please ?? 
Thank you very much :)

N.B. : I can't find the framework in the Release directory : /Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/RunInTheCity/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos so I can't verify the lipo.

Answer (score 1):

Try also adding armv7s. Default architectur

Comment: Since around Xcode 6 armv7s is excluded from the Standard Architectures and isn't required in order to submit apps. See link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040497/xcode-6-standard-architectures-exclude-armv7s